# can you modify my program to use "y/n" statement in c

Tags: c

Here, i am writing a c programming code i need help form you guys! I want to modify my program and want to use this in a loop i.e if a user enters "y" & if "n" will be entered it must end the program, I am trying this with switch case, I tried my best to end the program, it is returning to end but i don't know how to use "y" value for running the program again!

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char n, A, B;
   float kmTOm = 0.621371;
   float inchesTOfoot = 0.0833333;
   float cmTOinches = 0.393701;
   float poundtokg = 0.453592;
   float inchesTOmeter = 0.0254;
   float a, b;
   while (1)
   {
      printf("Enter the input character. q to quit\n1. kms to miles\n2. inches to foot\n3. cms to inches\n4. pound to kgs\n5. inches to meters\n");

      scanf(" %c", &n);
      switch (n)
      {
      case 'q':
         printf("Quitting the program...");
         goto end;
         break;
      case '1':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * kmTOm;
         printf("%.2f Kms is equal to %.2f Miles\n\n\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '2':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * inchesTOfoot;
         printf("%f Inches is equal to %f Foot\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '3':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * cmTOinches;
         printf("%f Cms is equal to %f Inches\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '4':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * poundtokg;
         printf("%f Pounds is equal to Kgs %f \n", a, b);
         break;
      case '5':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * inchesTOmeter;
         printf("%f inches is equal to %f meters \n", a, b);
         break;
      default:
         printf("In default now");
         break;
      }
   }
end:
   return 0;
}
```

I want a kindful modification from you developers to help me as I am a beginner and learing from a month, I except that the actual output must come like this ----o/p- do you want to quit press "q" ,do you want to run again press "y"

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps you could spend some time laying out your code using Markdown -- see this guide for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Also, consider changing all caps to normal text perhaps...

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but it is generally a bad idea to use goto statements in code.  It would be better to check a boolean value in the while statement and set that value in the 'q' case.

Comment: If the user presses `y` you still need to enter a menu choice. In fact you'll need to *another loop* for key entry because apparently only `y` or `n` will be acceptable responses. Keep it simple, and use `default` to report "invalid response".

Answer (score 0):

If you change the while(1) to a variable, then you can test after every loop whether it's time to exit.

The changes I made to your code all have comments below:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char n, A, B;
   float kmTOm = 0.621371;
   float inchesTOfoot = 0.0833333;
   float cmTOinches = 0.393701;
   float poundtokg = 0.453592;
   float inchesTOmeter = 0.0254;
   float a, b;
   n = 'y';  //set n to make sure while repeats 
   while (n != 'n') //change while to test "n" instead of 1, this way the value of n can be changed and the loop can be exited
   {
      printf("Enter the input character. q to quit\n1. kms to miles\n2. inches to foot\n3. cms to inches\n4. po
und to kgs\n5. inches to meters\n");

      scanf(" %c", &n);
      switch (n)
      {
      case 'q':
         printf("Quitting the program...");
         return(0); //exit entire program
         break;
      case '1':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * kmTOm;
         printf("%.2f Kms is equal to %.2f Miles\n\n\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '2':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * inchesTOfoot;
         printf("%f Inches is equal to %f Foot\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '3':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * cmTOinches;
         printf("%f Cms is equal to %f Inches\n", a, b);
         break;
      case '4':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * poundtokg;
         printf("%f Pounds is equal to Kgs %f \n", a, b);
         break;
      case '5':
         printf("Enter quantity in terms of a unit\n");
         scanf("%f", &a);
         b = a * inchesTOmeter;
         printf("%f inches is equal to %f meters \n", a, b);
         break;
      default:
         printf("In default now");
         break;
      } 

        //Ask the user if they want to run again.  The code will exit if the user types 'n', it will repeat if they type anything else (including 'y').
        printf("\nRun again? y/n:");
        scanf(" %c",&n);

   } 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting `end` to the value `false` to quit the program seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @HAL9000 I suppose a better name for the variable would be "continue".  Thank you for the suggestion. I'll edit it.

Comment: `contonue` is a keyword, and not a good choice for a variable either. Maybe just scrap the varible, and test for `n=='y'` in the loop condition

Comment: @HAL9000 a much more elegant solution, thank you. Edited to reflect.